# How to statically link to MSVCP120.dll in VS2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, dll, linker, visual-studio-2013

When I launch .exe it gives error MSVCP120.dll is missing. How do I add statically link to project. Is it in Linker? Do I need to give path to MSVCP120.dll?

Answer (score 3):

In general, you should not use static CRT linking as it creates a number of potential problems, security risks, and servicing concerns. You can require the VC++ REDIST package to be run (which requires admin rights) to install the 'system' version, you can use the VC++ MSM modules with your own MSI installer, or you can just use side-by-side deployment and put the DLLs in the same folder as your EXE.

See [Redistributing Visual C++ Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms235299.aspx)

You can use static linking for Win32 desktop apps, but there's only a few places where such use is warranted (namely pre-installation utilities). The CRT settings are the same as other Visual Studio editions as part of the compilation as a [command-line switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx) or a setting in the IDE under Project Properties / C/C++ / Code Generation to either "Multi-threaded (/MT)" or "Multi-threaded debug (/MTd)"

You cannot use static linking for Windows Store apps, Windows phone 8.x, or Xbox One apps.

Comment: It's Windows Desktop app. I cant use /MT since it's C++ app. If I use I get error D8016: '/clr' and '/MT' command-line options are incompatible. So I guess I have to use /MD. But then how do I add dll's through VS2013?

Comment: If you are using /clr it is not a "C++ app", but rather it's a "Managed C++ app" which is a different thing. And no you can't use static linking there either. The DLL dependacy is implicit by the use of /MD, so you don't add the DLLs to your project explicitly, but you do need them present on the target system when you run that EXE.